# save created excel file on server

Tags: asp.net, excel

I'm creating an excel file using Respose.Write in ASP.NET C#, my users can save the created file on their systems, but I want to save this excel file on my server, without user knowing anything about it. how is it possible? this is how I create my Excel file:

```
        Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + "res" + ".xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
```

....

```
    Response.Write("</table>");
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
```

this code saves created excel file client PC, but I want to save created file on the server

Comment: You should read up on basic file system input and output in C#. Your question indicates that you haven't even tried to solve this on your own before asking.

Comment: How are you generating your Excel file?  It looks like by generating an HTML table, right?

Comment: yes I'm generating it as an HTML table, I can give it to my client for download, but know I want to save it on server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general idea is to write the contents of the Excel file to a buffer.  Then a) save it to a file and b) stream it to the client.  You will want to use a unique file naming convention on the server (include a time stamp for example).  The IIS App Pool also needs write permission on the folder where you are saving the file to.

```
StringBuilder excel = new StringBuilder();
excel.Append("<table>");
...
excel.Append("</table>");

// save to file
File.WriteAllText("C:\\blah.xls", excel.ToString());

// output to response
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + "res" + ".xls");
Response.Charset = "";
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.Write(excel.ToString());
Response.End();
```